# Please confirm behaviour of collate database_default in TempDB

Tags: sql-server, collation

I am uncertain of which collation is used when a temp table is created with

```
create table #temp 
( object varchar(16) COLLATE database_default
, lev int )
```

E.g. does this use the TempDB collation or the user database collation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Ben's answer I did the following.  This makes it clear that the collation of the User database is used.

```
/* Find Collation of SQL Server Database */

SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('objective', 'Collation')
-- Latin1_General_BIN2

SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('tempDB', 'Collation')
-- SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

GO

/* Find Collation of SQL Server Database Table Column */

USE objective
GO

create table #temp
( id int
, word varchar(10))

select collation_name
from tempdb.sys.columns
where OBJECT_ID = object_id('tempdb.dbo.#temp');
-- SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS


create table #temp2
( id int
, word varchar(10) COLLATE database_default)

select collation_name
from tempdb.sys.columns
where OBJECT_ID = object_id('tempdb.dbo.#temp2');
-- Latin1_General_BIN2
```

Answer (score 0):

It uses the collation of tempdb. I tested on my local machine by setting the collation for one of my user databases to Albanian_BIN (which, notably, is different than the collation for tempdb) and running:

```
create table #foo (a varchar(100), b nvarchar(100));
select collation_name
from tempdb.sys.columns
where OBJECT_ID = object_id('tempdb.dbo.#foo');
```

This came back with two rows, both of which reflected the collation of tempdb.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ben.  It gave me an idea on how to prove it but in your example you had not set the collation of the nvarchar field to database_default.  See my answer.

Comment: That's the point of database_default - absent an explicitly provided collation, "text" columns inherit the default. And your question was "which database's default do they inherit?". If you provide a collation on the column, the answer is "it inherits neither - it will use the collation you provided". What am I missing?

Comment: Hi Ben - database_default is not a specific collation.  I had encountered issues that led me to wonder if the tempDB or the User DB collation was being used and the documentation was not clear.  Everything I read made reference to it using the database collation, but there are 2 databases involved.